# React function after dom has finished rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a map of the world and whenever you click on a particular country, it pings and API and gets schools in that country. React then uses leaflet to display all the dots(GEOJSON). After the schools are loaded I have a Dock type thing that will pop up. The problem is that I need to know when the react is done updating. I tried using the react lifecycle methods in the Map.jsx file I have the following code to try to see when the GEOJSON is done rendering:

```
componentWillUpdate() {
   console.log('CWU');
}
componentDidUpdate() {
   console.log('CDU');
}
```

But in the console I get the following printouts:

```
CWU, CDU, CWU, CDU, CWU, CDU
```

So both functions run 3 times, for another country both functions run twice. So I cant put the function that brings up the Dock in either componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate because I would need to run the function after the 3rd 'CDU' or for the other country after the second 'CDU'. Is there anyway way to know when react has finished rendering ?

Comment: You should probably figure out *why* the component is updated multiple times, and if you can avoid that.

Comment: @Timo that would be great but unfortunately react rerenders for a lot of reasons ie [link](http://lucybain.com/blog/2017/react-js-when-to-rerender/) It would be great if I could get react to just rerender once. But that sort of my control unless I specify all the conditions that should make react render (componentShouldRender)

Comment: Could you share more code, how you do API calls? I think you should not worry about, when React is done rendering, but rather hook on event, when API call is finished and update the state to show Dock there.

Comment: The reason why I care about when react is done is because rendering is what times some time. I get the data relatively fast but the rendering is what takes a while, hence why I want to know when the rendering is done/finished updating.

Comment: Hmm interesting, maybe you could compare previous props and current props of that component ? For example, if you are passing loaded items via prop like `items` and that property is equal to previous during componentDidUpdate, then that means that component rerender for a different reason than your data being loaded.

Comment: Yeah thats what I ended up doing. I needed to compare both props in the componentWillUpdate and componentDidUpdate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to solve it. I'll try my best to explain it:
I have a state variable called

```
didUpdate = false
```

The API changes a particular entry in the props 
so in componentWillUpdate I check to see if the next state is different than my current one if so I set didUpdate to false.  This makes it so that it doesn't display.

Then in my componentDidUpdate I check to see if previous state is different than my current one if so I then set didUpdate to true. This then makes it so the dock is shown.

Here is some code:

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (nextProps.X !== this.props.X) {
        this.setState({
          didUpdate: false,
        })
    }
}
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevProps.X !==this.props.X) {
        this.setState({
            didUpdate: true
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use

```
componentWillUnmount()
```

componentWillUnmount() is invoked immediately before a component is unmounted and destroyed. Perform any necessary cleanup in this method, such as invalidating timers, canceling network requests, or cleaning up any subscriptions that were created in componentDidMount().

Comment: How does this answer the question regarding when a component has finished rendering?

Comment: A component may re-render a couple of times as many times the state will change, but component there will be no re-rendering after a component has unmounted. This is what i understand, please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: What makes you think anything is unmounting based on the question? OP is asking how to determine if a component is done rendering.